# Fill in and correct null end dates in start/end sequences

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Problem**

I have a data set that looks like the following:

| EmployeeID | effectiveStartDate | effectiveEndDate | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-5-1 | NULL | 15 |
| 1 | 2023-2-9 | 2023-7-17 | 12 |
| 1 | 2023-6-25 | NULL | 13.18 |
| 2 | 2023-6-25 | 2023-8-24 | 12 |
| 2 | 2023-8-20 | NULL | 13 |
| 2 | 2023-4-4 | 2023-7-17 | 11 |

As you can see, for the two employees it's not a clear start/end correlation.

**Background**

Unfortunately, the data set is coming from Paycor's API, so I have no flexibility in the initial data set.  The complete data set is much larger, but these two in particular are giving me problems.  The data will be used to calculate labor costs against time card data up to the last hour (max) but also YTD and MTD.

**Goal**

I'd ideally like to take this data and make the start/end 'correct' with the only NULLs essentially being the current rate.  It would look like this:

| EmployeeID | effectiveStartDate | effectiveEndDate | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-5-1 | 2023-6-24 | 15 |
| 1 | 2023-2-9 | 2023-4-30 | 12 |
| 1 | 2023-6-25 | NULL | 13.18 |
| 2 | 2023-6-25 | 2023-8-19 | 12 |
| 2 | 2023-8-20 | NULL | 13 |
| 2 | 2023-4-4 | 2023-6-24 | 11 |

**Attempts**

I've tried a few things to solve this, but nothing seems to make sense and I'm back to square one.  I'm thinking I may have to partition somehow or leverage a calendar table but I can't put those pieces together in my head.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you not just use `LEAD` to just get the value of the *next* `effectiveStartDate` for the `effectiveEndDate`?

Comment: can there be holes? ie. non-overlapping periods per employee?

Comment: @Thom A: I legit have never heard of using LEAD or LAG.  I'm not a dba, to be clear, I'm just the best I've got (which is trying to learn)!  I did note your comments on Start/End:  I was just cleaning up the longer names for the sake of simplification for the post.  I swapped for actual to avoid per your point.  Regardless, I'm reviewing the suggestion below, thank you!

Comment: @ThomA: I see my question received a negative feedback, but I'm not sure why.  Do you have any suggestion on how I could have worded it differently to have avoided this?  I'm assuming some was because I used "SQL Server" in the title originally rather than trusting the tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simplified approach compared to the other answers; there's no need for a CTE or 2 scans of the table. You can just use `LEAD` to get the next start date and subtract 1 day from that:

```sql
--Sample table
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeeRate(RateID int IDENTITY(1,1), --So we can maintain your ordering
                              EmployeeID int,
                              StartDate date,
                              EndDate date, --End is a reserved keyword; I suggest picking a different name for your column, like I have here
                              Rate decimal(12,2));

--Sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeRate (EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate, Rate)
VALUES (1, '20230501', NULL, 15),
       (1, '20230209', '20230717', 12),
       (1, '20230625', NULL, 13.18),
       (2, '20230625', '20230824', 12),
       (2, '20230820', NULL, 13),
       (2, '20230404', '20230717', 11);
GO
--Solution
SELECT ER.EmployeeID,
       ER.StartDate,
       LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, -1, ER.StartDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY ER.EmployeeID ORDER BY ER.StartDate) AS EndDate,
       ER.Rate
FROM dbo.EmployeeRate ER
ORDER BY RateID ASC;

GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.EmployeeRate;
```

Comment: While you are correct that I didn't need a CTE like in @geek45's suggestion, it would require adding the RateID, which isn't a big deal, but was not in the original data set.  But I did test this and it produced exactly the same as geek45's answer.  A lot easier for me to comprehend what's happening as well.  Meaning it's an elegant solution.

Comment: The `RateID` is purely to maintain the ordering, @SaintFrag , as noted in the comment and I *assumed* you had one. You don't need the `RateID`,however, if you don't just know that your data will be returned in a different order, and it likely wouldn't reflect your expected results (which has no obvious order to it).

Comment: True, the order I get out of Paycor's API can be random and I'm not concerned about the order that comes out of this as it'll be used in additional joins to get the labor costs.  I was focused so much on learning how Lead plays into this, I didn't get the RateID too much attention: Obviously now that you've pointed it out, it's inconsequential, making yours the better answer all around.  Thanks for sticking with me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `LAG` and `LEAD` will help you out. Try to avoid using keywords to name variables so you can save on the square brackets...

```
WITH CorrectedPayRates AS (
  SELECT
    EmployeeID,
    Rate,
    [Start] AS OriginalStartDate,
    [End] AS OriginalEndDate,
    LAG([End]) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY [Start]) AS PreviousEndDate,
    LEAD([Start]) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY [Start]) AS NextStartDate
  FROM PayRates
)
SELECT
  EmployeeID,
  OriginalStartDate AS effectiveStartDate,
  DATEADD(DAY, -1, NextStartDate) AS effectiveEndDate,
  Rate AS payrate
FROM CorrectedPayRates
WHERE OriginalStartDate IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
  EmployeeID,
  OriginalStartDate AS effectiveStartDate,
  NULL AS effectiveEndDate,
  Rate AS payrate
FROM CorrectedPayRates
WHERE OriginalStartDate IS NULL
ORDER BY EmployeeID, effectiveStartDate;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JTb0c-OA)

| EmployeeID | effectiveStartDate | effectiveEndDate | payrate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-09 | 2023-04-30 | 12.00 |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 2023-06-24 | 15.00 |
| 1 | 2023-06-25 | *null* | 13.18 |
| 2 | 2023-04-04 | 2023-06-24 | 11.00 |
| 2 | 2023-06-25 | 2023-08-19 | 12.00 |
| 2 | 2023-08-20 | *null* | 13.00 |

Comment: This worked exactly as I'd hoped, thank you.